# Xamarin Forms 1 view binded to multiple objects

Tags: c#, object, xamarin, binding, multibinding

So I gotta question how to bind multiple objects to 1 view since from what I've gathered you cant bind more than one object a.k.a content to per view. I got data coming from SQL db and mongo db, Projects from one and products from other. I want to be able to enter data from view based on project and product model and display it into a third object mixed from 2previous. idea is to generate an inventory log of products that were taken out of the warehouse for certain projects.

Comment: create a ViewModel that contains all of the data needed for a given View

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can create a ViewModel which contains all the data(multiple objects) you need to bind to your view.

You can refer to the offical sample [Xamarin.Forms - CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-collectionviewdemos/).

Take one page [VerticalListSinglePreSelectionPage.xaml](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/UserInterface/CollectionViewDemos/CollectionViewDemos/Views/Selection/VerticalListSinglePreSelectionPage.xaml)  for example, we can add our data into the viewmodel [MonkeysViewModel.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/UserInterface/CollectionViewDemos/CollectionViewDemos/ViewModels/MonkeysViewModel.cs) as follows:

```
   public class MonkeysViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    readonly IList<Monkey> source;
    Monkey selectedMonkey;
    int selectionCount = 1;

    public ObservableCollection<Monkey> Monkeys { get; private set; }
    public IList<Monkey> EmptyMonkeys { get; private set; }

    public Monkey SelectedMonkey
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedMonkey;
        }
        set
        {
            if (selectedMonkey != value)
            {
                selectedMonkey = value;
            }
        }
    }

    ObservableCollection<object> selectedMonkeys;
    public ObservableCollection<object> SelectedMonkeys
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedMonkeys;
        }
        set
        {
            if (selectedMonkeys != value)
            {
                selectedMonkeys = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public string SelectedMonkeyMessage { get; private set; }

   // other code
}
```

And we can bind the multiple objects in xaml, here we bind `SelectedMonkeyMessage`,`Monkeys` ,`SelectedMonkey` and Command `MonkeySelectionChangedCommand` in page [VerticalListSinglePreSelectionPage.xaml](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/UserInterface/CollectionViewDemos/CollectionViewDemos/Views/Selection/VerticalListSinglePreSelectionPage.xaml),just as follows:

```
<StackLayout Margin="20">
    <Label Text="{Binding SelectedMonkeyMessage}" />
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMonkey}"
                    SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding MonkeySelectionChangedCommand}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Padding="10">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                           Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" 
                           Aspect="AspectFill"
                           HeightRequest="60" 
                           WidthRequest="60" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" 
                           Text="{Binding Name}" 
                           FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="1"
                           Grid.Column="1" 
                           Text="{Binding Location}"
                           FontAttributes="Italic" 
                           VerticalOptions="End" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
 </StackLayout>
```